# Sending email not send email using filter_var

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have problem when i filter data befor sent email. Mail is not sent i try `Gmail` and `Yahoo` but not delivered. This my code work perfect on sub-domain but on main doman not working and that is intresting.

**Check my code:**

```
    $this->db->where('user_id', $userInsertid);
    $this->db->update('users', $update);

    $this->db->where('id','1');
    $query          = $this->db->get('mail_templates');
    $mailtemp       = $query->result_array();
    $message        = $mailtemp['0']['mail_message'];
    $fromEmail      = $mailtemp['0']['mail_from'];
    $subject        = $mailtemp['0']['mail_subject'];
    $toEmail        = $this->input->post('email');
    $urls           ='<a target="_blank" href="'.base_url().'register/verify/'.$tuno.'">click here</a>';

    $logo=base_url().'skin/site/images/logo.png';

    $message = str_replace('#name', $this->input->post('firstName'), $message);
    $message = str_replace('#adminemail',$fromEmail, $message);
    $message = str_replace('#username', "Msg", $message);
    $message = str_replace('#password', "qwe123", $message);
    $message = str_replace('#verifyurl', $urls, $message);
    $message = str_replace('#logo', $logo, $message);
    $message = str_replace('#sitename',"ASD", $message);

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: <support@mysite.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: <support@mysite.com>' . "\r\n";

    $email = filter_var($toEmail, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $sub = filter_var($subject, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    mail($email,$sub,$message,$headers); // <-- NOT WORK
    mail('myemail@gmail.com','Test Subject',$message,$headers); // <-- WORK
```

Here is dump of `$mailtemp`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [mail_from] => support@mysite.com
            [mail_subject] => User Registration
            [mail_message] => <HTML tempalte>
            [created_at] => 2014-09-28 15:31:23
            [created_by] => 1
            [modified_at] => 2016-06-04 07:10:06
            [modified_by] => 1
        )

)
```

If i manual set email and subject in `mail()` function that was successfull sent to gmail and yahoo. 
I also try to escape and trim email and subject before pass to `mail` function but again not work. This `headers` is okay and work on sub-domain like i say

What can be problem here ?

Comment: What's the value of `$this->input->post('email')` ?

Comment: `print_r($this->input->post('email');die();` return my email what i input in form field `$_POST['email'] => as******@gmail.com`

Comment: what is value of $email after the $email = filter_var($toEmail, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); statement.

Comment: @SumanSingh you have ansver above its my email address from `$_POST['email']`

Comment: `var_dump($toEmail)` return `string(21) "ad*******@gmail.com"`. Dump after `filter_var`

Comment: Cant beleve is `DUPLICATED` show that duplicate for this problem... NVM